# Animating UIViewController's frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create an animation. When I click on an image, the view expands the from this frame to the view of the `UIViewController` to the bounds of whole screen on pushing it on the `navigationController` and shrinking to the same size while popping it back. I was able to create the pushing animation but unsuccessful in my attempt to create the popping animation.

```
// Code in the controller which pushes the controller on the stack

self.navigationController.view.center = center;
self.navigationController.view.frame = frame;
self.navigationController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1f, 0.1f);

// Code in the viewDidAppear of controller being pushed to the stack

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                         self.navigationController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                         self.navigationController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
                         self.navigationController.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

This works properly but I tried the following code for pop animation in the `viewDidDisappear`, where `initialFrame` is the frame on which I am tapping to open the `UIViewController`.

```
// Code for viewDidDisappear
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1f, 0.1f);
                     self.view.frame = self.initialFrame;
                     self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.initialFrame.size.width/2 + self.initialFrame.origin.x, self.initialFrame.size.height/2 + self.initialFrame.origin.y);}
                 completion:nil];
```

I am not able to make the pop animation work. Please help me out.

Comment: have you tried setting the transform as the last of the three properties!? E.g. setting the frame, then setting the center, then setting the transform?!

Comment: @luk2302 After looking at your comment, tried it too. Doesn't work. Why do you think it should work?

Comment: Because the frame property behaves differently when a transform has been set. At least i had this issue a few hours ago.